# IrfanView does not ask before deleting

Tags: windows-10, irfanview

I want to set IrfanView at my Windows 10 to ask me always before deleting a file (moving it to the trash).

There is an option in Settings -> File Handling -> Delete: `Ask me before deleting files (if activated in Recycle bin settings)` - I have marked this option and also `Delete to Recycle Bin`. See image below.

But any confirmation message does not show if I press the Delete button and the image is instantly moved to the trash.

I tried IrfanView version 4.52 x86, 4.52 x64 and 4.51 x86 and it is always the same.

How can I fix it?

[image: Image: IrfanView - settings]

Comment: Oh, thank you! I didn't know this.

Comment: Converted comment to answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Any confirmation message does not show if I press Delete

Have you checked your Recycle Bin settings? "Display delete confirmation dialog" must be checked there for this to work:

> 1. Use <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> shortcut to view the desktop.
> 2. Right-click the Recycle Bin icon, and select the Properties option.
> 3. Check the Display delete confirmation dialog option.
>
> [image]

Source [How to change Recycle Bin storage settings on Windows 10 | Windows Central](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-change-recycle-bin-storage-settings-windows-10#confirm_delete_windows10)

Answer (score 1):

This can be a bigger problem when viewing files on external drives, or other storage areas where files cannot be moved to the Recycle Bin (Windows would prompt you to ask if you want to permanently delete the file). In that case, the file doesn't even go to the Recycle Bin and will be permanently deleted.

If you notice you deleted the file (accidentally pressed DEL for example), and it is still open in the viewer, make sure to save it which will create the file again. Once you move off of it in the viewer memory it would be gone forever.

Answer (score 0):

You can also completely disable the Delete File keyboard shortcut, toolbar button and the menu item using an option.

From the [Irfanview Frequently Asked Questions](https://www.irfanview.com/faq.htm#PAGE13) page:

> A: In the global INI file (located in the IrfanView folder), you can set some Admin values in correct INI sections:
>
> ...
>
> 2. Disable deleting of single files:
>
>    ```
>    [Others]
>    Admin_EnableDelete = 0 or 1
>    ```
>
>    (1 means: deleting enabled (default); 0 means: deleting disabled)

While this wasn't the question, I've found that I delete pictures by accident way more often than actually using this shortcut to clean up images, as the Delete key is frequently at the top right of a laptop keyboard and is easy to press when Backspace was intended.